# How to remove or hide videofile extn in qt

Tags: qt, file

I am having one insert button from which I can select video files either from phone memory or memory card.but all the files are coming with name and extn(.3gp).

How I will remove this or hide this in QT?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're looking for the [`QFileInfo::baseName`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qfileinfo.html#baseName) function. Do this:

```
QFileInfo( "/path/to/videofile.3gp" ).baseName()
```

This will return "videofile".

Answer (score 0):

void FileListWidget::displayVideoFiles()
    {
        QStringList filters;
        if(isFileMedia)
            filters += "*.3gp";
        else
            filters += "*.txt";
        clear();
        addItems(dirPath.entryList(filters, QDir::AllEntries));
    }

the path of the video file is _LIT(KPhoneMemory,"C:\Data\Videos");

how i will implement QFileInfo( "/path/to/videofile.3gp" ).baseName()